# Ordering MongoDB query results in less rows returned

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm having an issue with ordering in Mongoid (2.0.0.beta.17 and 2.0.2)/MongoDB. Perhaps I'm just not experienced enough with MongoDB, and some of you can help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

The user-level symptoms are:

- Queries not sorting correctly by date or ID
- User posts are not appearing when they seem like they should be (this is a Twitter-like [social networking site for gardeners](http://www.plantworking.com), and the most recent posts are sometimes not showing up)

---

```
irb(main):024:0> Update.all.size
```

=> **551**

```
Update.ordered.size     # (see below for definition)
```

=> **490**

```
irb(main):010:0> Update.all.select{|u| u.created_at.nil?}
```

=> []

When I go into the mongo shell, and do:

```
var cursor = db.updates.find({}, {'_id': 1}).limit(600); 
while (cursor.hasNext()) printjson(cursor.next());
```

I get **454** lines returned.

```
var cursor = db.updates.find({}, {'_id': 1}).sort({created_at : 1}).limit(600); 
while (cursor.hasNext()) printjson(cursor.next());
```

Also returns **454** lines.

```
db.updates.find({}).sort({created_at: -1}).limit(1);
```

returns an update from February 23rd. But I have updates from yesterday in MongoDB. 
Any ideas?

---

My model is:

```
class Update 
  include Mongoid::Document 
  include Mongoid::Timestamps 
  include Paperclip 
  field :body 
  ... 
  index [[ :created_at, Mongo::DESCENDING ]] 
  ... 
  named_scope :ordered, :order_by => ([[:created_at, :desc]]) 
  ... 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out WHY, but doing the following seems to fix the problem:

named_scope :ordered, :order_by => ([[:created_at, :desc], [:_id, :desc]])

It seems the secondary ordering helps.

```
irb(main):022:0> update = Update.order_by([[:created_at, :desc], [:_id, :desc]])

irb(main):025:0> update.count
=> 556
irb(main):026:0> update.first.created_at
=> Sat May 28 02:53:33 -0700 2011
irb(main):027:0> update.second.created_at
=> Fri May 27 17:55:38 -0700 2011
irb(main):028:0> update.first.created_at.class
=> Time
irb(main):029:0> update.second.created_at.class
=> Time
```

The first of these was being left out of the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print out the `created_at` field?

```
db.updates.find({}, {created_at:1}).sort({created_at: -1}).forEach(printjson)
```

You may have an issue with how you're saving your date fields. Is the output there a string? an ISODate()?

Comment: They're all the same, of Time class when instantiated. 454 of them. Thank you for your suggestion!